# pisa 2 не отображает кирилицу

Tags: python, django

При создании pdf файла кирилицу выдаёт чёрными квадратами. Не понимаю как это пофиксить. Сам times new romans рендерится на английском языке. а рендерить укр/рус не хочет. В html странице всё рендериться , а вот в пдф файл уже не хочет

есть utils.py

```
# encoding: utf-8

from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template


from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def fetch_pdf_resources(uri, rel):
    if uri.find(settings.MEDIA_URL) != -1:
        path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.MEDIA_URL, ''))
    elif uri.find(settings.STATIC_URL) != -1:
        path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.STATIC_URL, ''))
    else:
        path = None
    return path

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode('UTF-8')), result, encoding='utf-8',link_callback=fetch_pdf_resources)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

есть view.py которая генерирует пдф файл.

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.template.loader import get_template
from .utils import render_to_pdf

class GeneratePDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
        template = get_template('pdf_gen.html')
        context = {
            "customer_name": "John cooper",
            "amount": 123231,
            "today": "Today",
        }
        html = template.render(context)
        pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf_gen.html' , context)
        if pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type = 'application/pdf')
            filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" %("213231231")
            content = "inline; filename = '%s'" %(filename)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response
        return  HttpResponse("Not found")
```

и сам код html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face { font-family: Times New Roman; src: url"{% static 'css_styles/times-new-roman.ttf' %}"; }
            body{
              font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            }
            body {
                font-weight: 200;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            .header {
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: 100;
                text-align: center;
                color: #007cae;
            }
            .title {
                font-size: 22px;
                font-weight: 100;
               /* text-align: right;*/
               padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;  
            }
            .title span {
                color: #007cae;
            }
            .details {
                padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
                text-align: left !important;
                /*margin-left: 40%;*/
            }
            .hrItem {
                border: none;
                height: 1px;
                /* Set the hr color */
                color: #333; /* old IE */
                background-color: #fff; /* Modern Browsers */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <div class='header'>
                <p class='title'>  </p>
            </div>
        <div>
        <div class='details'>
        ф
        івфівфівфівфіпкщенузхк
        ущзехцщузхе
            asdasd
            щзщзщз
            іівівфівфі<br>
            sdasdasdasdasldkas;ldkaskd
            kasl
            dkaslkd
            kla;ksd;laks;ldkal
            sdk
            askdl;askdlkasl;dkaitweoptiwerkwel;kfslcx,cmz/x
            <!-- <hr class='hrItem' /> -->
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решения которое смогли реализовать, это в fetch_pdf_resources передать прямой путь к шрифту.

```
def fetch_pdf_resources(uri, rel):
if uri.find(settings.STATIC_URL) != 0:
    # path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.STATIC_URL, ''))
    path = r'< прямой путь к шрифтам >'
else:
    path = None
print(path)
return path
```